# using a textview within an intentservice android

Tags: android, textview, android-intentservice

I have created a textview within my MainActivity and i need to pass this into my IntentService 
as I need to use the textview from MainActivity somewhere else. Is it possible to use the findViewById within an IntentService or is there a method in order to be able to do something similar that will allow that TextView to be used within the IntentService?

Thanks

Comment: Service does not have a ui. You can use Handler or LocalBroadCastReciever or Third party library like EventBus and then update ui in Activity itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use `putExtra` to save your textview id in intent:

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(ListaActivity.this, ListDetailActivity.class); 
i1.putExtra("YourKey", "your textview id".toString()); 
startActivity(i1);
```

To retrieve the information:

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String textViewID = intent.getStringExtra("YourKey");
```